# How to initialise Bootstrap data attributes API?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

This has bugged me for a while, when using the JavaScript components, I can't seem to figure out how to use them via the `Data Attributes` API, the so called first class API.

E.g. the modal, as per the [documentation](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals):

```
<a href="#CreateTable" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Add Mortality Table</a>
<div id="CreateTable" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"  aria-hidden="true">
        Hello
</div>
```

Now from I can tell all I need to do is have `bootstrap.js` include on the page and when I click the link, the modal should pop up.

But it doesn't I need to add an event listener like so:

```
$('.modal').click(function(){
    $("#CreateTable").modal();
});
```

Only then the modal will open, is there something I am missing? Do I have to intialise the bootstrap.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems to be working. I copied your html into a jsfiddle here.

```
<a href="#CreateTable" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Add Mortality Table</a><div id="CreateTable" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"  aria-hidden="true">Hello</div>
```

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/g30rg3/cX7ME/1/)

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#CreateTable").modal();
});
</script>
```

Comment: That is what I'm trying to aviod, http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript/#js-data-attrs